# Canning white meat

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]

**Across**
1. Singing is temporarily entertaining tenor (4)
3. Old Levantine-American from Arizona (10)
10. Striking hard, a pharaoh mutilated a tribe's member (7)
11. Small sound – crying? (7)
12. Strongly decline military equipment (4)
13. Something four-footed to wobble around public transport (10)
16. Jackie's working for music (7)
17. Port-of-Spain – capital described by poems of excellent quality (6)
21. Scared of a strong attack (6)
22. *(See 9 down)*
25. Opportune as one dressed in black (10)
27. Garment to go around heads (4)
29. Video devices became energy-free during tailor's retirement (7)
31. Extraordinary times ultimately passed riding a three-wheeler (7)
32. A bean buyer prepared aromatic plant (5,5)
33. Support party's leader that is right (4)

**Down**
1/19. Large formation of soldier ants set off course (6,8)
2. A boat might use one of each sonar, perhaps (3,6)
4. Can Spooner's white meat? In what way? (8)
5. Awarded war drama covering short-reigning king (6)
6. Occasionally, Citroën leads to annoyance (3)
7. Green Day sang about an American, one looking up to an African leader (5)
8. Like many internet scammers earning suspiciously, drawing in innocent beginner (8)
9/22a. Ford Transit perhaps moving English monster hunter (3,7)
14. Unimpressive central idea in the majority (6)
15. Yours truly doing badly, being blue (6)
18. Mix-up of rations in part of Greece (9)
19. *(See 1 down)*
20. Alien not resorting to revival of old language (3-5)
23. Foreign assault besieging capital (6)
24. Emblem attached to king's hound (6)
26. Colour of Queen vocalist's insides? (5)
28. In bad taste as spoken – and as written (3)
30. Article on essential novel, the second of Martin Gardner (3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filled grid:

> [image]

Clue explanations:

> [image]

Comment: l can't see the two lmgur pictures.

Comment: @Scratch---Cat Then you should probably find a workaround, because stack.imgur.com is the canonical way to share things on Stack Exchange. For now, here are temporary links to the [grid](https://gyazo.com/95769e6a7fd58ea175211ad43a6ac445) and [clue explanations](https://gyazo.com/9701d238e4d9ce5a61a1f65ae5d2c669): hopefully these work for you.

Comment: Those websites are too sIow.